# Does UI5 Remember's previous entity

Tags: sapui5

I am building simple crud for an entity.  Initial state is read on particular entity(key) using `view>form.bindElement('/entity(key)')`.

when I click on new button I clear the form and  when the cancel button is clicked during the new/create process(without performing the save), how to go back to the previous entity. Is there some place ui5 stores, the previous entity or should I have some variable and assign it to the `controller.previousEntity = oldsPath`?

what are the different members in the oModel,it start with

a(aBindings)

b(bUseBatch)

m(mContexts)

o(oHeaders)

p(pCallAsync)

s(sPathUrl).

Is there a naming convention in these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, there are following things you need to notice and work upon.

- Its generally not a good idea if you use the same form to display and to create/update also. A simpler approach would be to

> use a new popover to show the form for create and in that case, the view binding would not be changed when you cancel the operation.

However, if you still want to use the same form, yes you would have to bind the view/form again on cancel operation. You can have a variable declared in the Component.js to store the path for you. In UI5, the model captures the current state to ensure the back the binding concept by default.

- You can check all properties and their definitions here: [oData Model](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel)

Yes, there is a naming convention followed here. 
a - Array, s-String, b- Boolean etc.

[Read more about Hungarian notations for naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Examples)

Answer (score 0):

The previous entity is still there in the cache (ODataModel.oData), but you'll need to re-bind it. For that purpose, as you have written, you'll need to store the path to the entity yourself. Once you bind the control, I don't think the previous binding context is stored somewhere (why should it).